# Power outage during installation of Internet Explorer 8 update

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer-8, windows-update

Yesterday I was installing 56 updates on my newly installed Vista Home Basic SP1. The 40th of them was IE8 and just when it was installing I had a power outage. After reboot Vista recognized there was a problem and... uninstalled all 40 updates and then rebooted again. After opening Windows Update I saw all the 56 updates available for installation. I started installing them and all went well, except IE8 update failed because... "there was already a newer version installed"! I checked and indeed I've IE8 running fine.

But Windows Update **keeps offering it** and it fails every time.

I tried to uninstall IE8 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957700/en-us), but I cannot do it the easy way, because it's not visible in the installed updates list. So I tried the alternative steps described there. It seemed to work, but when I started IE and looked at the "about" dialog - it **still says it's IE8**.

Before I contact MS support - does anyone know any other method to uninstall IE8, so that the update can be installed correctly?

Comment: you can always hide that update

Comment: I know I can hide it - but I'm afraid it may block some newer updates when they're available

Comment: I know this isn't very helpful for your current problem, but in hindsight, you might have benefited from having a small UPS for your PC.  I have a small UPS for each of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a [System Restore](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/) point prior to the installation of the updates?

If you restore to this point you should be able to start the update process all over again which hopefully will mean the updates go through this time.

Comment: that looks like a good idea; it's just that I've installed some other software afterward (Office 2007 for one) so it'd rollback everything, wouldn't it?

Comment: I think you would need to install Office again but I'm not sure.  System Restore makes a Restore Point when you do a revert so you should be able to get back to where you are now if you don't like where the revert takes you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading the installer from

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=79154fb4-c610-4a1e-811d-dfe0f1dd84d1

and running it manually.

Comment: I tried, but the installer complains that I already have that version installed. Guess I'll have to wait for IE 9 ;)